# HTML5 development with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

I am new to the web world and I am asked to developed an HTML5 website using Visual Studio 2012. I have the following questions:

1. Can someone give me a link on how to set up visual studio 2012 to create HTML5 applications ? I tried to create a new project but didn t find an option for HTML5 applications at all?
2. Can someone suggest a good youtube page or tutorial page on how to develop HTML5 websites using visual studio 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 is a newer version of HTML for browsers that support the features that comprise it.  You may want to start by reading the [wiki entry for HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5).

The [W3C completed the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/News/2012#entry-9667) earlier this week (December 17, 2012).

Before focusing on what features Visual Studio 2012 provides for developing HTML5 web applications, I'd suggest learning [what HTML5 is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), [how it works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335062.aspx), and [what browsers support what features](http://caniuse.com/).

A great place to start reading is [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/).

Answer (score 0):

you can refer : http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/asp-net-hello-html5

And if you are in hurry,can jump directly to 6th min in this video, for the straight forward answer to this Question.